# Checking a column if it is equal to an array of numbers mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

How can I check an int array for this query? I made the query only for checking inregistrari.ID_camera= 101
for example how could i check if inregistrari.ID_camera = 101, 501 ..

```
SELECT DISTINCT(ID_camera), tip_confort.nume_tip_confort,
       COALESCE(SUM(inregistrari.ID_camera = '101'),0) AS nr_pers_in_camera, 
       locatii.nume_locatie, camere.nr_persoane_max  
  FROM inregistrari 
NATURAL JOIN camere 
NATURAL JOIN tip_confort 
NATURAL JOIN locatii 
  WHERE camere.ID_tip_confort =3 AND ID_camera=101;
```

The result of my query is:
[image]

The desired Result

[image]

Comment: `WHERE camere.ID_tip_confort = 3 AND ID_camera in (101, 501);` For reference see [MySQL IN](https://www.mysqltutorial.org/sql-in.aspx/)

Comment: it doesn't work, because I tried, even if I put it that way, it just prints me a line

Comment: Your requirement is not clear. Post sample data and expected results to clarify.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You still not provided the structure and sample data of `locatii` table but I think can use the `group by` as follows:

```
SELECT ID_camera, 
       tip_confort.nume_tip_confort,      
       Count(*) AS nr_pers_in_camera, 
       locatii.nume_locatie, 
       camere.nr_persoane_max  
  FROM inregistrari 
  NATURAL JOIN camere 
  NATURAL JOIN tip_confort 
  NATURAL JOIN locatii 
 WHERE camere.ID_tip_confort =3 
   AND ID_camera in (101,501)
 Group by ID_camera, 
          tip_confort.nume_tip_confort,
          locatii.nume_locatie,
          camere.nr_persoane_max
```